# How to divide HighCharts column in different categories?

Tags: angular, charts, highcharts, angular-material

I need 3 categories for the `Xaxis` and I want to show a particular column only in particular `xAxis` category. Also, I want to open a modal on every column click function. My main problem is with dividing columns into particular categories.

[image: current chart implementation example]

Jsfiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/dinesh1099/5r4a1ko8/ . I want Adhoc vehicle and Fixed Vehicle only in the Cost category.

Comment: Please can you edit your post and provide more informations on what you exactly want to do? Can you also give an example from jsfiddle or stackblitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of categories, you can use data labels and position them as you want. For example:

```
chart: {
  type: 'column',
  events: {
    load: function(){
      var chart = this;

      this.series.forEach(function(s){
        s.points.forEach(function(p){
          p.dataLabel.attr({
            y: chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(0) - chart.plotTop - 12
          });
        });
      });
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7yud3pm8/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.dataLabels